# Enterprise bot msbot clone services command hangs

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I've created a bot from the VS Enterprise bot template. When I run the "msbot clone services" command, it hangs in the middle of the script after creating the Azure Search service. There are no apparent errors running --verbose but the script is clearly hung and only installs half of the services in Azure.

Azure shows all the steps so far a successful. Can anyone suggest how to get more logging information than using the --verbose flag?

```
D:\Dev\sobot181214\sobot181214    msbot clone services --name "sobot181214" --luisAuthoringKey "**REDACTED**" --folder "DeploymentScripts\en" --location "westus" --verbose
Checking az botservice version
az -v
checking dotnet requirement
dotnet --version
Fetching subscription account
az account show
The following services will be created by this operation:
 Service                                 Location            SKU                 Resource Group
 Azure App Site Plan                     westus              S1                  sobot181214
 Azure AppInsights Service               West US 2           F0                  sobot181214
Azure Blob Storage Service              westus              Standard_LRS        sobot181214
 Azure Bot Service Registration          Global                                  sobot181214
 Azure CosmosDB Service                  westus              1 write region      sobot181214
 Azure LUIS Cognitive Service            westus              S0                  sobot181214
 Azure LUIS Cognitive Service            westus              S0                  sobot181214
 (Dispatch)
 Azure QnA Maker Service                 westus              S0                  sobot181214
 Azure Search Service                    westus              Standard            sobot181214
 Azure WebApp Service (Bot)              westus                                  sobot181214
 Azure WebApp Service (QnA)              westus                                  sobot181214
Resources will be created in subscription: Pay-As-You-Go Dev/Test (**REDACTED**)
Would you like to perform this operation? [y/n]y
Creating Azure group [sobot181214]
az group create -g sobot181214 -l westus --subscription **REDACTED**
Creating Azure Bot Service [sobot181214]
az bot create -g sobot181214 --name sobot181214 --kind webapp --location westus --insights-location "West US 2" --subscription **REDACTED** --version v4 --    lang CSharp --verbose
[az bot] INFO: Microsoft application id not passed as a parameter. Provisioning a new Microsoft application.
 (Please be patient, this may take several minutes)
[az bot] To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code xxxxxxx to authenticate.

Fetching bot extended information [sobot181214]
az bot show -g sobot181214 -n sobot181214 --subscription **REDACTED**
Fetching co-created resources [sobot181214]
az resource list -g sobot181214 --subscription **REDACTED**
Fetching bot website appsettings [sobot181214]
az webapp config appsettings list -g sobot181214 -n sobot1812141nay --subscription **REDACTED**
Creating LUIS Cognitive Service [sobot181214-LUIS]
az cognitiveservices account create -g sobot181214 --kind LUIS -n "sobot181214-LUIS" --location westus --sku S0 --yes --subscription **REDACTED**
Fetching LUIS Keys [sobot181214-LUIS]
az cognitiveservices account keys list -g sobot181214 -n "sobot181214-LUIS" --subscription **REDACTED**
Creating site plan [sobot181214]
az appservice plan create -g  sobot181214 --sku s1 --name sobot181214 --subscription **REDACTED**
Creating Azure Search Service [sobot181214-search]
az search service create -g sobot181214 -n "sobot181214-search" --location westus --sku standard --subscription **REDACTED**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the code snippet and output log that you have provided, I see that it was successfully executing various commands (i.e., creating group, creating bot, showing bot, listing resource, listing webapp config appsettings, creating cognitiveservices account, listing cognitiveservices account keys, creating appservice plan respectively) until it has reached the step to create search service. But I think there was some issue while creation of appservice plan step or even while creation of bot step. So just to understand the issue better, by chance if you have appservice plan named ‘sobot181214’ still available and bot webapp named ‘sobot181214’ still available then can you check if they are properly created or are they in a kind of corrupted or unstable state ?

Also the catch point is as per this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) link, it states that some users might experience issues if ‘--appId’ argument is not provided while running the command ‘msbot clone services’. So can you browse to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and manually create a new application retrieving the ApplicationID and Password/Secret. And then run the ‘msbot clone services’ command along with the arguments ‘--appId’ and --appSecret’ passing the values you have just retrieved and let me know the outcome. Also ensure that you wrap the secret with quotes to prevent parsing issues, e.g: --appSecret "YOUR_SECRET".

On the other hand, if you are interested to debug the current issue in detail, you may try to update all the ‘az’ commands in the script ‘C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\msbot\bin\msbot-clone-services.js’ appended at the end with ‘ --debug’ parameter which would increase the logging verbosity to show all debug logs while executing ‘msbot clone services’ command. But in some cases, updating ‘msbot-clone-services.js’ file corrupts the msbot related packages. In case if that happens then you may uninstall and re-install msbot and related packages by running the command ‘npm install -g ludown luis-apis qnamaker botdispatch msbot chatdown’ as instructed in this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) link.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I don't have that bot available anymore. We did manage to get this working but not through anything that we did. It's quite unsatisfying to say that it just started working. However, we'll be circling around to deployment again in the near future.